# Bug Compliance Level in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, buildpath

i got a problem with my Code... the Error Message is 
`'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7"` 
but im using 1.7. in Java Compiler, the Compiler Compliance Level is on 1.7 but this Message is still there... how can i fix this?

can anyone please help me?

Comment: Check the build path. Which library version is there on the build-path Settings ?

Comment: 'Workspace default JRE (jdk)' is marked

Comment: And your workspace default JRE is version 7 ?

Comment: schould be... where can i check this?

Comment: Window -> Preferences -> Installed JREs -> The one which is ticked is the default one

Comment: it just show me "jdk(default)" and the location and the type is "Standard VM"

Comment: if i type into the console "java -version" it shows me "java version 1.7.0_40"

Comment: Now that's the issue. Eclipse has nothing to do what you see in the console, you must add another JRE (it detects it automatically). Don't forget to update your project preferences too!

Comment: The java running on your console might be different from the one that eclipse may be using. It should be giving the path of the JDK that it is using. Can you add a new JRE to this list and point to the one that you want to use ? After adding , simply check the box and it will become your default one. Next , configure this new JRE on your build-path of the project

Comment: What problem you faced ?

Comment: its the same problem... i have add a new jre and configure my build path but it still doesnt work...

Comment: See my answer below @user3069881

Comment: Did you check the Compiler Compliance level in the project's properties as well?

Answer (score 0):

To setup JRE on your eclipse follow these instruction

1. Make sure that the JDK you want is extracted in some directory
2. In eclipse, goto *Window* --> *Preferences* --> *Installed JREs*
3. If the JDk configured there is not per your requirements, then simply add a new one. To add, Click Add --> Standard VM --> Specify the path to your JDK (not JRE) and click ok.
4. Tick the Check-box next to the VM that you just configured in the *Installed JREs* screen.
5. Next, goto *Execution environment* (just below Installed JREs), Click on the Environment and map it with the relevant Compatible JREs. This way you can have multiple VMs configured inside eclipse and its easy to manage once you specify there Compatible JREs to eclipse
6. After finishing up, simple update the references in your project's build path. Your newly configured VM should be coming in the drop down, select it and Voila!